# public static (const) in a generic .NET class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, syntax

Is there a syntax trick to get to the constant in a generic class without specifying an (ad-hoc) type?

```
public class MyClass<T>{
    public const string MyConstant = "fortytwo";
}

// I try to avoid this type specification.
var doeswork = MyClass<object>.MyConstant;  

// Syntax similar to what I'd like to accomplish.
var doesnotwork = MyClass.MyConstant;
```

There is a caveat about the static variable (constant) not being shared between different types like `MyClass<object>` and `MyClass<int>` but my question is about possible available syntax trick.

Comment: You could create a non-generic class `MyClass` for the constant.

Comment: WARNING: Using `const` in public classes can cause headaches **if** the assembly is going to be referenced in another program or assembly. Use `readonly` instead.

Comment: Here's a [reference](http://www.stum.de/2009/01/14/const-strings-a-very-convenient-way-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot/) for @B0Andrew's warning

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Use a non-generic abstract parent class.**

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
   public const string MyConstant = "fortytwo";
}

public class MyClass<T> : MyClass
{
   // stuff
}

var doeswork = MyClass.MyConstant;
```

That of course assumes that there's some reason the constant needs to be part of the generic class; if it has public accessibility, I'm not seeing a reason why you wouldn't just put it in a separate class.

Having a non-generic abstract parent class is a good idea for *every* generic class you make; the generic class is actually a template for the specific subtype classes, rather than a true parent, so having a true non-generic parent can make some techniques (such as, but certainly not limited to, this one) a lot easier.

Comment: The reason I checked this as answer was that it was very short (=readable) and solved My Problem. Kudos to @MatthewWatson  for effort and time spent.

Comment: Your class names are inconsistent.

Comment: @Rawling In what sense?

Comment: `MyClass.MyConstant` won't compile as there is no `MyClass` class.

Comment: @Rawling Fixed. Someone else edited in the `doeswork` line that had the problem, but I approved the edit without looking as closely as I should have, so that's on me.

Comment: Sadly, this solution does not work anymore if your class extends another generic base class and you need to pass on T to your base class.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this works:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public class MyClass // Use a non-generic base class for the non-generic bits.
    {
        public const string MyConstant = "fortytwo";

        public static string MyString()
        {
            return MyConstant;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass<T>: MyClass // Derive the generic class
    {                                // from the non-generic one.
        public void Test(T item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MyConstant);
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MyClass.MyConstant);
            Console.WriteLine(MyClass.MyString());
        }
    }
}
```

This approach works for any static types or values that you want to provide which do not depend on the type parameter. It also works with static methods too.

(Note: If you don't want anybody to instantiate the base class, make it abstract.)