# How to get purpose field for userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, reset-password, usermanager

When I'm trying to reset a password, I'm using `userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, tokenProvider, purpose, token)` but it always returns false. My suspicion is that the `purpose` field is wrong but I'm not sure what should actually go there.
My question is, how do I get the `purpose` field? 
From some examples I've seen, people are setting it "ResetPassword". Is this correct or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
                options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "emailconfirmation";
            })
             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<VisualDbContext>()
             .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
             .AddTokenProvider<EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>("emailconfirmation");

            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opt =>
                opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

            services.Configure<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions>(opt =>
                opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3));
```

```cs
// Forgot Password
    var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    var encodedToken = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token);
```

```cs
//Verify Reset Token
    var purpose = "WHAT GOES HERE?";
    var result = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider, purpose, token);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 "token purpose" constants defined for you to use on the User Manager class, as you can see in the UserManager [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L29).

In your specific use case, you would want to do this:

```
//Replace TUser with your user type
var purpose = UserManager<TUser>.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose;
var result = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider, purpose, token);
```

Or you could do this:

```
var purpose = UserManager<object>.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose;
```

Unfortunately, because the UserManager class is generic, you have to write somewhat ugly code to access the constants. Maybe in the future, Microsoft could add a non generic parent class as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841936/public-static-const-in-a-generic-net-class), to make accessing the purpose constants more elegant.